# Using data in scoped slots?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a v-for in my component:

```
<li v-for="(item, index) in items"></li>
```

But this is also part of a scoped slot:

```
<div slot="modal">
    ....
    <li v-for="(item, index) in items"></li>
    ....
```

So, in the parent, how can I use my own HTML in the slot, but still use the `items` data from the child component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [scoped slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots).

First, in the child component, specify that the slot should have a reference to the `items` prop, by binding the array to the `slot` tag:

```
<slot name="modal" :items="items">
```

Then, in the parent component, you can access the `items` array by using the `slot-scope` directive:

```
<div slot="modal" slot-scope="props">
  <li v-for="(item, index) in props.items"></li>
</div>
```

Here, `props` is an object with all of the properties that have been bound to the child component's `slot` tag. So `props.items` references the `items` array from child component.

---

Here's a simple example:

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <slot name="foo" :items="items"></slot>
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return { items: ['a', 'b', 'c'] };
  }
})

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <child> 
    <ul slot="foo" slot-scope="props">
      <li v-for="(item, index) in props.items">
        {{ item }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </child>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - can I just ask, slot-scope="props", what if I want to pass in more data here? How would I do it?

Comment: Bind more properties to the `slot` tag in the child component.

Comment: Ok - and how are these [assed from the parent - slot-scope="props"

Comment: `<slot :items="items">` binds `items` from the child component to `props.items` in the parent's scope. So, if you wanted to add a `props.foo` property, you'd need to do something like `<slot :items="items" :foo="0">`

Comment: You have been a great help. Thanks.